# PHP log in system password isn't matching

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication

I have made a login system which enables a user to sign in using a previously defined email and password, however in the testing section, I have noticed the passwords say they don't match although I know they are correct as I wrote the test one down as I made it. I cant seem to see why this is happening, I think it may be something to do with my hashing of the passwords but I don't know what.The login page check is from document, login.php:

```
    if(empty($errors))
{
    $sql = "SELECT accountID, password FROM users WHERE emails=?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$data['email']]);

    if(!$row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        // email didn't match
        $errors['login'] = "Login failed. on email";
    }
    else
    {
        // email matched, test password
        if(!password_verify($data['password'],$row['password']))
        {
            // password didn't match
            $errors['login'] = "Login failed. on password";
        }
        else
        {
            // password matched
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['accountID'];
            header('location: welcome.php');
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

The insertion to the database with hashing is, from insert.php:

```
    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
        $pword = $_POST['password'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['busName'])){
        $busName = $_POST['busName'];
    }

    if (empty($name)){
        echo("Name is a required field");
        exit();
    }
    if (empty($email)){
        echo ("email is a required field");
        exit();
    }
    if (empty($pword)){
        echo("You must enter a password");
        exit();
    }
    $pword = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."/n";



//insert html form into database
$insertquery= "INSERT INTO  `cscw`.`users` (
`accountID` ,
`businessName` ,
`name` ,
`emails` ,
`password`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$busName',  '$name',  '$email',  '$pword'
);";
```

and on the web page i am shown from login.php, "Login failed. on password". If you need to see any more code please let me know.

Comment: Where does `$data` come from?

Comment: Loose this bit `."/n"` in your password_hash line

Comment: @FrankM $data = array_map('trim',$_POST);

Comment: @Yolo and then create users again)

Comment: @Yolo Thank you this has worked!

Comment: While it's commendable that you're trying to use prepared statements with placeholder values, and PDO at that, as well as the proper password hashing mechanism, keep in mind that any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in that's already implemented all of this and more. If you're approaching this from an academic understanding perspective, that's fine, but don't overlook those examples.

Comment: Your `$insertQuery` is not escaped properly, though, so that sort of undoes all of those previous efforts. That's a giant [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) and it often only takes *one* of those for someone to attack and subvert your system. It also appears your insert query is not actually executed, so you may want to check that it's actually run.

Answer (score 0):

**It does not recognize $row['password']**. 
*Be always organized with your query* **
1)Prepare 
2)Execute 
3)Fetch 
4)Close 
5)THEN YOU EXPLOIT the fetched data.
The fetched data need to be sorted as shown with the returnArray function.

Hoping that there are UNIQUE emails and the `$data` array exists.Try this.

```
if(empty($errors))
{

    $sql = "SELECT accountID, password FROM users WHERE emails=:emails";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':emails', $data['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->CloseCursor();
    $stmt=null;

    /* Return the results is a more handy way */
    function returnArray( $rows, $string )
    {
       foreach( $rows as $row )
       {
           return $row[ $string ];
       }
    }

   if( empty($rows) )
   {    // email didn't match
       $errors['login'] = "Login failed. on email";
   }
   else
   {      // email matched, test password
       if( !password_verify( $data['password'], returnArray($rows,'password') ) )
       {
          // password didn't match
          $errors['login'] = "Login failed. on password";
       }
       else
       {
          // password matched
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['accountID'];
          header('location: welcome.php');
          die;
       }
   }
}
```

---

The login Page is not finished the query is not inserting. Be carefull you might be vunerable to SQL injections because your do not escape user manipulated variables.(To strengthen security add a form validation, it will be great).

You have used `$pword = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."/n";`
I removed ."/n" part. I seems that you are using a concatenation operator '.' to add /n add the end of the password_hash.

Your $insertquery is not finished and not readable. You don't need to insert backticks in your query. And no need to SELECT accountID it will autoincrement (See if A_I for accountID is ticked in your database).
Do something like this in your login page.

```
/* trim and escape*/
function escapeHtmlTrimed( $data )
{
    $trimed = trim( $data );
    $htmlentities = htmlentities( $trimed, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' );
    return $htmlentities;
}


if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ){
    $name = escapeHtmlTrimed( $_POST['name'] );
}
if ( isset($_POST['email']) ){
    $email = escapeHtmlTrimed( $_POST['email'] );
}
if ( isset($_POST['password']) ){
    $pword = escapeHtmlTrimed( $_POST['password'] );
}
if ( isset($_POST['busName']) ){
    $busName = escapeHtmlTrimed( $_POST['busName'] );
}

if ( empty($name) ){
    echo("Name is a required field");
    exit();
}
if ( empty($email) ){
    echo ("email is a required field");
    exit();
}
if ( empty($pword) ){
    echo("You must enter a password");
    exit();
}
/*Remove this your adding "./n"*/
$pword = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);



//insert html form into database
$insertquery= "INSERT INTO users (businessName ,name ,emails, 
password) VALUES (:busName , :name, :email , :pword)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertquery);
$stmt->bindParam(':busName', $busName);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':pword', $pword);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->CloseCursor();
$stmt=null;
```